# sql count in group if same name count as 1

Tags: mysql

In my data base different different village and some same name village available i want to count them if same name village that count as 1 . but my query not show result or i not execute  my query properly . Please help .

You can check my database [sql filddle list here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0af97d/2/0)

```
SELECT vill, COUNT(*) as totalvv from mmdata  group by vill HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arnHr.png)

in the above pic you can see there same name count 6 time  i want if same name count that  as 1 and sum of the total number vill and show the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just remove the count(*) and give value=1 then make it as a sub-query. Then from the sub-query you sum the total village. Something like below:

```
SELECT SUM(totalvv) AS Total 
FROM (
 SELECT vill, 1 AS totalvv 
 FROM mainmar19
 WHERE MONTH='september' 
 AND taluk='কান্দারা' 
 GROUP BY vill 
 HAVING COUNT(*)>1
 ) A;
```

P/S: I took the query from your fiddle